What is the best way to set up self-hosted runners with ARC and GCP?
I'm in the midst of configuring self-hosted runners on GCP. Right now, I have 3 options that I'm considering:

GCE managed instance groups with SpotVMs
Standard GKE with SpotVMs
GKE Autopilot with SpotPods (I'm not sure if ARC can run with GKE Autopilot)

And I'm not sure which is best. Any input is appreciated 

As of March 29, 2023 - you cannot use ARC with GKE Autopilot. So, you're left with option 1 and 2.
I personally would lean on using Standard GKE because there are already existing community patterns to deploy [1].
[1]. https://github.blog/2020-08-04-github-actions-self-hosted-runners-on-google-cloud/
